# Нервувати і нервуватися - різниця вживання

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, дієслова

Я не розумію, як саме вживати ці слова. Наприклад, "чого ти нервуєш, заспокойся - все буде добре". На мою думку, ***нервувати*** може хтось інший, а не ти сам себе.

Визначення з СУМ запутали ще більше

> [Нервувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nervuvaty)1. неперех. Те саме, що нервуватися. 
>   2. перех. Приводити кого-небудь у стан нервового збудження, роздратування; прикро вражати чим-небудь.
>
> [Нервуватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/nervuvatysja) Бути в стані збудження, хвилювання, роздратування.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B20) подає обидва слова як синоніми.

Чи потрібно розмежовувати вживання слів? Чи вони абсолютні синоніми?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хоч СУМ вважає "нервувати" тим самим, що й "нервуватися", декілька інших джерел вказують на це як на помилку. Словопедія [cтверджує](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53405/25800.html):

> Часом "нервувати" використовують у не властивому йому значенні: “Вона
>   помітно нервувала і час від часу зиркала у вікно” (Петро Панч).
>   Нервувати людину може щось чи хтось інший, а не вона саму себе:
>   “Особливо це чомусь нервувало, непокоїло Никанора” (Іван Ле).  Якщо
>   треба передати стан збудження, роздратування, тоді доречне слово
>   нервуватися: “Бжеський нервувався і, чекаючи на відповідь,
>   роздратовано тарабанив пальцями по столу” (Зінаїда Тулуб).  Читаємо в
>   газеті: “У кабінеті слідчого Пархомчук нервує і ніяк не збереться з
>   думками”. Дієслово нервувати означає “приводити кого-небудь у стан
>   збудження, роздратування, прикро вражати”. Однак тут мовиться, що
>   Пархомчук сам у такому стані, отже, він не нервує, а нервується. Так і
>   потрібно було написати.

На сайті [Літературне місто](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21154) цю пару віднесли до cкладних випадків українського слововживання.

А на ресурсі [мова – ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/nervuvatu-j-nervuvatusya) цій парі присвятили окремий графічний слайд:

[image: "Нервувати й нервуватися"]

Отже, схиляюся до думки, що ці слова варто розділяти.